# How to compute $||e_m||_1$ and $||Ae_m||_1$ and use it to prove

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

1. Let m be the index of the column of A with maximum 1 norm. That is, ||a<sub>m</sub>||<sub>1</sub> >= ||a<sub>i</sub>||<sub>1</sub> for 1 <= i <= n. Let e<sub>m</sub> be the standard basis vector that has e<sub>m</sub>(m) = 1 and e<sub>m</sub>(i) = 0 for i != m. Compute ||e<sub>m</sub>||<sub>1</sub> and ||Ae<sub>m</sub>||<sub>1</sub>.
2. Show that ||A||<sub>1</sub> = max<sub>1<=I<=n</sub>||a<sub>i/sub>||<sub>1</sub>.</sub>

For:

1. I know that
   ||Ax|| <= ||A|| * ||x||
   as well as the definitions for the 1-norm of a vector and the induced matrix norm but I don't know how they are useful in solving the question.
2. I know that I need to show that both the >= and <= inequalities hold and I need to use ||Ax||<sub>1</sub> <= max<sub>1<=I<=n</sub>||a<sub>i</sub>||1.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts for part 1 are not relevant to the question. The point of the question is to observe that $Ae_m = a_m$, which means that $\|Ae_m\| = \|a_m\|$.

This question is helpful for part $2$ because it gives us a lower-bound for $\|A\|_1$. Indeed,
$$
\|A\|_1 = \max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\|_1 \leq \|Ae_n\| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} \|a_i\|.
$$
So, in order to answer question to, we need only show that $\|A\|_1 \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq m}\|a_i\|$. Equivalently, we need to show that for a vector $x$ satisfying $\|x\|_1=1$, we have $\|Ax\| \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq m}$.

As a hint towards how to obtain this inequality, begin by using the triangle inequality to note that
$$
\left\|Ax \right\|_1 = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n  x_i a_i \right\|_1 \leq 
\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\cdot \|a_i\|_1.
$$

Comment: Hi, I have proven that ||Ax||<sub>1<sub> <= (max<sub>1<=i<=n<sub>||a<sub>i<sub>||<sub>1<sub>)||x||<sub>1<sub>

But I am not sure how to use this to prove 2

Comment: @user1092808 If $\|Ax\| \leq C$ holds for all $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$, then it follows that $\max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\| \leq C$.

Comment: How do I go about solving 1?

Comment: The only thing that you need to write for part 1 is that $\|e_m\|_1 = 1$ and $\|Ae_m\|_1 = \|a_m\|$.

Comment: ||em||1 = 1 because em(m) = 1? And why is ||Aem||1 = ||am|| and what does ||am|| equal to?

Comment: @user1092808 Your first question is phrased a bit imprecisely, but it is indeed the case that $\|v\|_1 = 1$ for any standard basis vector $v$. For any $i$, $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. I don't understand what you mean by "what does $\|a_m\|$ equal to". By the way, [here's the help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format mathematical expressions on this site using Mathjax.

Comment: Hi, why is it that ||Ae_m|| = ||a_m|| and does ||a_m|| equate to a specific numerical value will writing ||Ae_m|| = ||a_m|| suffice. Thank you

Comment: To your first question: as I said, $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. So, $Ae_m = a_m$. So, $\|Ae_m\| = \|a_m\|$. To your second, How could $\|a_m\|$ be a specific numerical value if this question is about an unspecified matrix $A$? For the purposes of answering part 1, writing $\|e_m\| = 1$ and $\|Ae_m\| = \|a_m\|$ will suffice.